# Crear botones en Android programaticamente

Tags: android

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en Android y deseo agregar en uno de mis activitys unos botones, que deben ser añadidos según crean los usuarios, entonces debo poder crearlos dinámicamente.

También quisiera que cambien de color según ciertos estados de los usuarios y además quisiera que cambien de posición, que aparezca uno u otro botón primero según sea el caso.

¿Qué herramientas de Android me recomiendan que use?

Saludos.

Comment: Bienvenid@ a StackOverflow, en su pregunta veo tres preguntas, ademas no aporta ningun codigo o alguna orientacion de lo que ha intentado para solucionarlo, le sugiero que edite esta pregunta para dejarla como una sola. La 1º Estoy ......... crearlos dinamicamente. La 2º que cambien de color segun ciertos usuarios y La 3º que cambien de posicion. Pero creo que seria mejor que se centre en la primera y despues publique las siguientes como nuevas preguntas osea 2º y 3º con algo en lo que este trabajando, pero solo es  una opinion Saludos

Comment: ¿Qué herramientas de Android me recomiendan que use? no se aque se refiere pero creo que con estas vas servido http://developer.android.com/intl/es/sdk/index.html Saludos

Comment: Estos link igual le ayudan de alguna manera pues dinamicamente es muy abierto para los detalles que pone. 1º -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851633/how-to-add-a-button-dynamically-in-android 2º -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710200/android-programmatically-adding-buttons-to-a-layout 3º -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4MFzuP1F-xQ Saludos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Debes crear botones dinamicamente, usando un layout personalizado para tu botón, también puedes modificar las propiedades del mismo según lo requieras, por ejemplo puedes modificar el texto, su color, el icono, incluso su posición...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este sería un código que demuestra lo que comento:

```
    LinearLayout btnsContainer = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    btnsContainer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    btnsContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    btnsContainer.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    //Crea botons dinamicamente.
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        final LinearLayout buttonContainer = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_button,null);
        ImageView btnImg = (ImageView) buttonContainer.findViewById(R.id.btn_image);
        TextView btnTxt = (TextView) buttonContainer.findViewById(R.id.btn_text);
        btnTxt.setText("mi Botón no." +  i);
        btnTxt.setBackgroundColor(getRandomColor());
        btnImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        buttonContainer.setTag(i);

        buttonContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Listener botón " + v.getTag() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        //Va agregegando botones al contenedor.
        btnsContainer.addView(buttonContainer);
    }
    //Crea contenedor para agregar contenedor de botones.
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams paramsContainer = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(400, 1500, Gravity.CENTER);
    //Agrega contenedor con botones.
    addContentView(btnsContainer, paramsContainer);
```

Función para obtener colores aleatorios:

```
public int getRandomColor(){
   Random rnd = new Random();
   return Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
}
```

Este sería el layout del botón personalizado `item_button.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10px"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@null"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btn_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#F0F0F0" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: jaja veo que te animaste a contestar, es que es raro que yo diga esto pero la veia muy abierta su pregunta, -> "entonces debo poder crearlos dinámicamente" Pero cuando.   -> "también quisiera que cambien de color según ciertos estados de los usuarios" Que usuario/estados. -> "y además quisiera que cambien de posición, que aparezca uno u otro botón primero según sea el caso" Que caso. Pero me alegra que tenga esta informacion en español, yo le deje unos link de mas o menos lo que tu publicaste pero en ingles, pense que con esos link podria ir trabajando. Saludos

Comment: Hola @AngelAngel si, me parece un poco abierta la pregunta pero pues sería la única forma de hacer todas esas preguntas jeje, saludos!

Comment: lo implemente pero solamente muestra 8 botones de los 100 que se generaron. Como hacer para que se vean todos deslizando la pantalla en forma vertical como es la intencion, gracias

Comment: @GuidoImbachiFdz agrega los botones dentro de un scrollview.