# Paint con colores aleatorios

Tags: java, android

Tengo el siguiente `onDraw`:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawRect(rectangulo,paint);
}
```

Me gustaría saber cómo implementar para que no fuera solo `Color.RED` si no que fueran colores aleatorios.

¿Algo así como un array con varios colores y el set color lo llame?

---

Este es mi código:

```
private static final int[] colores = {Color.GREEN,Color.BLUE,Color.RED};
```

En el constructor:

```
r = new Random();
num = r.nextInt(3);
```

y el Ondraw:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  paint = new Paint();
  paint.setColor(colores[num]);
  canvas.drawRect(rectangulo,paint);
}
```

Comment: quieres que cada vez que se llame al `onDraw` sea un color aleatorio o un color aleatorio dentro de unas opciones siempre las mismas?

Comment: Cada vez que se llame al onDraw sea un color aleatorio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para eso puedes hacer uso de este método:

```
public int getRandomColor(){
    Random rnd = new Random();
    return Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
}
```

Que es usado en este ejemplo:
[Botones en Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6000/botones-en-android/6007#6007). Para llamar el método, simplemente lo realizas de esta forma:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(getRandomColor()); //Asigna un color aleatorio.
    canvas.drawRect(rectangulo,paint);
}
```

para que cada vez que el método `onDraw()` sea llamado, pinte un color aleatorio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Lo más sencillo para colores aleatorios es:

```
new Color((int)(Math.random() * 0x1000000))
```

Quedando tu método:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(new Color((int)(Math.random() * 0x1000000)));
    canvas.drawRect(rectangulo,paint);
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/VdqoPJ)

---

Otra manera es crear cada valor de `RGB` individualmente.

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Random r = new Random();
    Color randomColor = new Color( r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256) );
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(randomColor);
    canvas.drawRect(rectangulo,paint);
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/4j1VaV)

<sub>Nota: Hay que importar `java.util.Random`</sub>

Comment: Me erronea con el int

Comment: qué error te da? en mi demo te funciona?

Comment: si! pero he cambiado el codigo y como este onDraw me sera provisional me sirve! Muchas gracias

Comment: Me alegra ser de ayuda. puse otro modo por si lo que sea te interesa más. Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

Puedes crear colores aleatoriamente sin usar el Paint

```
private String getRandomColor() {
String color = "#";
String[] a = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
int r = (int) (Math.random()*  (16 -1) +1);
int g = (int) (Math.random()*  (16 -1) +1);
while (g == r) {
g = (int) (Math.random()*  (16 -1) +1);
}
int b = (int) (Math.random()*  (16 -1) +1);
while (b == r || b == g) {
b = (int) (Math.random()*  (16 -1) +1);
}
color += a[r] + a[g] + a[b];
return color;
}
```