# ¿Se puede crear una matriz de Buttons en Android?

Tags: android

tengo 9 grillas de 9 botones cada uno. En cada grilla se generan 9 números Aleatorios del 1 al 9. (Es para un sudoku). Necesito que un número de una grilla no se repita en otra grilla.

Ejemplo

9 3 5      9 6 **1** 2 7 8

3 6 4.   2 5  7.     3 1 8

2 8 7.   4 3 **8**.   1. **7**9

1 3 5      9 6 **1** 2 7 8

4 6 4.   2 5  7.     3 1 8

2 8 7.   4 3 **8**.   1. **7**9

5 3 5      9 6 **1** 2 7 8

9 6 4.   2 5  7.     3 1 8

7 8 7.   4 3 **8**.   1. **7**9

Debe formarse números del 1 al 9 en cada cuadricula pero también debe ser del uno al nueve en cada fila y columna. Cada fila o columna debe tener los siguientes números 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 entonces yo necesito crear un algoritmo o metodo para que no se repitan los números al ser creados aleatoriamente en el método onCreate.

Hay un método que genera 9 números aleatorios en cada grilla de 9 Buttons pero estos no pueden repetirse en la grilla anterior.

Había pensado hacer un método que diga

```
while (button1 == button2 || button1 == button3 || button1 == button4 || button1 == button5 etc {

//Genera nuevamente numeros aleatorios siempre que un numero sea igual a otro de su fila

generarNumerosAleatorios();
}
```

Pero esto sería muy largo y entonces pensé que se podía hacer con una matriz

Comment: No estaría entendiendo: Si tengo 9 botones, en cada botón hay un número, y los números van del 1 al 9, entonces en cada grilla se usan todos los números. En las 8 siguientes grillas se van a repetir todos los números de la primera. Me parece que falta algo en la explicación del problema, o si es muy complejo un ejemplo claro.

Comment: Si se puede realizar lo que deseas, revisa esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6000/crear-botones-en-android-programaticamente

Comment: Lo estas encarando mal, no necesitas numeros aleatorios, los numeros siempre son los mismos en un sudoku, lo que necesitas es un ordenamiento aleatorio. Podes crear 10 arrays de numeros del 1 al 10, luego mezclas los numeros del primer array y lo agregas a una matriz, mezclas los numeros del segundo array, pruebas que no se esten repitiendo los numeros y que toda la cuestion y lo metes a la matriz, asi hasta que se termina todo.

Comment: @Juan yo creé 9 métodos que es para que los 9 botones se generen aleatoriamente. Generar1 genera los de la primera cuadricula, generar 2 genera los de la segunda etc.

Comment: Disculpame pero para mi el ejemplo es de lo más confuso: hay filas que tienen puntos y filas que no. Numeros separados por espacio y números que no. Y tanto en las filas como en las columnas se repiten números. Y lo mas fundamental no queda claro a que le llamas grilla (una fila, una columa, o un cuadrado de 3 x 3, o a otra cosa).