# TextView dinámicos a partir de un TextView ya definido en XML

Tags: java, android-studio, textview

tengo el siguiente "TextView" definido es un "XML":

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewSubjects"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:text="@string/teacher_subjects"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewMail" />
```

Y de forma dinámica quiero añadir una lista de "TextView" mediate código java, que hasta el momento tengo así:

```
this.subjects = subjects;

List<TextView> textViewList = new ArrayList<>();

for (Subject subject : subjects) {
    LayoutParams params =
        new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());

    textView.setText(subject.getName());
    textView.setLayoutParams(params);
    textView.setPadding(LEFT, TOP, RIGHT, BOTTOM);

    textViewList.add(textView);
}
```

Quisiera saber cual es la manera de indicar la posición en el "XML" para los elementos de la lista usando el "TextView" que ya tengo.

Gracias.

Edición 1:

He añadido una serie de atributos para cada "TextView" de la lista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad lo importante es definir primeramente un contenedor en el cual se agregarìan los TextView, al agregarlos puedes modificar su posiciòn definiendo los parametros al usar el mètodo [addView(View, params)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#addView(android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
//Cambia posiciòn.
params.leftMargin = 20; 
params.topMargin = 30;

//Agrega TextVies al contenedor con posiciòn definida.
textsContainer.addView(buttonContainer, params);
```

Ejemplo:

```
LinearLayout textsContainer = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
textsContainer.setLayoutParams(new 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
textsContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
textsContainer.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

//Crea TextViews dinamicamente.
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    ...
    ...

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
    //Cambia posiciòn.
    params.leftMargin = i + 10; 
    params.topMargin = i + 10;

    //Agrega TextVies al contenedor.
    textsContainer.addView(buttonContainer, params);

}
```

a modo de ejemplo puedes ver esta respuesta que es similar pero con botones que se agregan dinamicamente:

[Crear botones en Android programaticamente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/6007/95)