# Posicionando vistas en Android/Java. ¿Cómo mostrar varias vistas?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Estoy tratando de posicionar varias vistas dinámicamente en Java en relación a los píxeles de alto y ancho de la pantalla del dispositivo, pero la única manera que se me ocurre es llamando a setContentView(). Esto hace que solo se vea la última vista cargada.

```
public class MesaSeis extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mesa_seis);
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    
        int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(     "@drawable/mesa_azul", null, getPackageName() );
        Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
        ImageView mesa = new ImageView(this);
        mesa.setImageDrawable(res);
        int posXMesa = width/10;
        int posYMesa = height/6;
        mesa.setX(posXMesa);
        mesa.setY(posYMesa);
        setContentView(mesa);
        mesa.getLayoutParams().height = 3*height/5;
        mesa.getLayoutParams().width = 3*width/5;

        TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
        tv1.setText("Lolo");
        tv1.setX(0);
        tv1.setY(0);
        setContentView(tv1);   
    }
}
```

El problema entiendo es que no puedo llamar cada vista a setContentView. ¿Cómo hay que hacerlo para cargar varias vistas?, ¿he de crear un layout principal que sea el que paso en setContentView y añadirle vistas? ¿O he de añadir las vistas al xml y desde Java solo posicionarlas?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres específicamente con vistas, a pantallas? ¿Si la pantalla  uno se ve, como accedes a la pantalla seis? Al acceder a la pantalla seis, ¿Qué sucede con la pantalla uno?

Comment: Deseas crear las vistas programaticamente verdad?

Comment: @Franqo Balsamo Me refiero a cargar la imagen y los texview. Es una mesa de poker. Deseo hacerlo todo desde Java, pero imagino que solo puedo llamar a setContentView una vez. No sé si tengo que crear un layout padre o qué. Si me podéis pasar algún tutorial que lo explique.

Comment: @Elenasys Sí, deseo hacerlo todo desde Java. Es una mesa de poker.

Comment: @Elenasys pero no sé si la manera de hacerlo es cargar las vistas en el xml y desde Java solo posicionarlas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema principal es que estas agregando la última vista al contenedor principal.

```
setContentView(tv1);
```

**Lo que debes de realizar es agregar un layout y ahí agregar las vistas.
No es necesario usar `setContentView()` ya que tu estas creando el contenido**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout myContainer= new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    myContainer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    myContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    myContainer.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

    int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/mesa_azul", null, getPackageName() );
    Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
    ImageView mesa = new ImageView(this);
    mesa.setImageDrawable(res);
    int posXMesa = width/10;
    int posYMesa = height/6;
    mesa.setX(posXMesa);
    mesa.setY(posYMesa);
    //setContentView(mesa);
    mesa.getLayoutParams().height = 3*height/5;
    mesa.getLayoutParams().width = 3*width/5;
        
    if(mesa.getParent() != null) {
        ((ViewGroup)mesa.getParent()).removeView(mesa); //Remueve vistas antes de agregar.
    }

    myContainer.addView(mesa); //Agrega vista a contenedor

    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
    tv1.setText("Lolo");
    tv1.setX(0);
    tv1.setY(0);

    myContainer.addView(tv1); //Agrega vista a contenedor

   // setContentView(tv1);

    //Crea parametros para contenedor.
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams paramsContainer = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(400, 1500, Gravity.CENTER);
    //Agrega contenedor con vistas.
    addContentView(myContainer, paramsContainer);

   }
```

Revisa también :

[Crear botones en Android programaticamente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6000/crear-botones-en-android-programaticamente)

Comment: Gracias. Creo que te has dejado la línea `setContentView(mesa);` , que se trata de evitar llamar ese método.

Comment: Si!, no se usa setContentView(), se crea un contenedor con elementos y se agrega este contenedor a la vista mediante : addContentView

Comment: El problema es que no se posicionan las views correctamente. Lo he solucionado añadiendo un RelativeLayout, pasándolo en el setContentView y añadiendo vistas con un margen, que indica la posición.

Answer (score 1):

Lo he solucionado creando un RelativeLayout y posicionando las vistas con un margen izquierdo y superior (lo que indicaría su posición).

```
public class MesaSeis extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView mesa;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params,params2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

        RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
    
        int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(     "@drawable/mesa_azul", null, getPackageName() );
        Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
        mesa = new ImageView(this);
        mesa.setImageDrawable(res);
        params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(3*width/5, 3*height/5);
        params.leftMargin = width/10;
        params.topMargin = height/6;
        rl.addView(mesa, params);

        TextView tvplayer1 = new TextView(this);
        tvplayer1.setText("Lolo");
        params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 50);
        params2.leftMargin = width/30;
        params2.topMargin = 8*height/10;
        rl.addView(tvplayer1, params2);

        setContentView(rl);
    }
}
```

Comment: Esto es lo que comento en mi respuesta, entonces no fue útil para tí?

Comment: @Elenasys Sí, aprendí que había que tener uno principal y hacer `addView()`y luego puse el RelativeLayout. El problema de tu código creo que viene de hacer `FrameLayout.LayoutParams paramsContainer = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(400, 1500, Gravity.CENTER);` y luego no puedo posicionar desde (0,0) los items. Marco este porque permite posicionar las vistas en términos absolutos.

Comment: En tu pregunta no indicas que deseas posicionar las vistas en determinada forma solo comentas "posicionar varias vistas dinámicamente en Java", por eso agregue como ejemplo el LinearLayout y Framelayout como parámetros pero se supone que puedes usar cualquier tipo de layout como el RelativeLayout, es importante agregar detalles a las preguntas para que se puedan responder de forma correcta y añadir detalles, revisar [ask].

Comment: @Elenasys pero el problema es que tu código cogido del mío el textview con texto Lolo no se posiciona arriba a la izquierda se posiciona por el medio cuando tienes setX(0) y setY(0)